# Error indexing partition after upgrading to dse 6.7.5 from 5.0.7

Tags: linux, cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0, nodetool

Upgrading to version 6.7.5 in dse from 5.0.7.I have snapshot of keyspace which is restored properly on dse version 6.7.5 but it gives error during indexing dfter creating core

> dsetool -l cassandra -p $CASSANDRA_PASSWORD reload_core us.lead reindex=true deleteAll=false
>   dsetool -l cassandra -p $CASSANDRA_PASSWORD reload_core us.product reindex=true deleteAll=false
>
> ERROR [CoreThread-0] 2019-09-26 14:16:57,891 AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1482 - Error indexing partition 'CON-PSOP-CP-7975G' on 'us.product':
>
> Error indexing partition '5270' on 'us.lead':
>   com.datastax.bdp.search.SearchReadBeforeWriteException: Unable to complete Search read-before-write.
>       at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.readBeforeWriteError(AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:2071)
>       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleResumeNext$ResumeMainSingleObserver.onError(SingleResumeNext.java:73)
>       at org.apache.cassandra.utils.flow.Flow$1SingleFromFlow$1ReduceToSingle.signalError(Flow.java:1539)
>
> Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.CorruptSSTableException: Corrupted: /var/lib/cassandra/data/us/product-336e8d60df7d11e98ee3e99aa5a3a4fa/mc-439-big-Data.db

Due to this error solr user interface is also not working but dse service is running on the node and in nodetool status both the nodes are up having approximately same load.

Also tried to upgradesstables command but below issue occurred

`nodetool upgradesstables us lead`

> error: EOF after 245554130 bytes out of 1818583396

--StackTrace –

> java.io.EOFException: EOF after 245554130 bytes out of 1818583396 at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.RebufferingInputStream.readFully(RebufferingInputStream.java:70) at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.RebufferingInputStream.readFully(RebufferingInputStream.java:62) at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.read(ByteBufferUtil.java:472)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, your data file is broken. You need to use [nodetool scrub](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.7/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/tools/nodetool/toolsScrub.html) to try to get as much data from this file as possible.  After that, use `nodetool rebuild` to resync data for this table.